# How to parse HTTP requests

Tags: go, instagram

I am making a http request to instagram using http.Get , I was wondering if there was a faster way to check if there is a certain line of text, e.g. I request only part of the html.

tdlr: How do I only get part of the http request.

Code currently works but I would like it faster.

```golang
resp, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("https://www.instagram.com/%s", line))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        // IF RES HERE. ( after bodystring := string(body)
        bodystring := string(body)
        res1 := strings.Contains(bodystring, "<h2>Sorry, this page isn&#39;t available.</h2>")
        if res1 == true {
```

Comment: What part specifically are you looking for? You could use https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Tokenizer together with the `resp.Body` to walk through the html until you find what you're looking for and then exit, without having to read the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a task such as this, checking if content was found, it's faster and more reliable to check the [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of the [Response](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response).

```
resp, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("https://www.instagram.com/%s", line))
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalln(err)
}
if resp.StatusCode == 404 {
  // page was not found
}
```